# CSS "fill-mode:forwards" not working in Safari

Tags: css, animation, mobile, safari, mobile-safari

For some odd reason, `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` is not working in safari. I'm not sure why, because it works in every other browser. Here is the code:

```
.fade {
        opacity: 0;
       -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
       -moz-animation:fadein 2s;
       -ms-animation: fadein 2s;

        -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
        -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
        -ms-animation-duration: 2s;

        -webkit-animation-delay: .9s;
        -moz-animation-delay: .9s;
        -ms-animation-delay: .9s;

        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

The website where you can see this taking place is http://uiuxpert.com

Any ideas what's going on? Everything looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was right.
I just needed to clear the cache and do a hard refresh. For some reason it took a while..spotty internet today. :)